# Move element to the right with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Basically, I'm trying to move my hamburger menu div to the right side of the page with Flexbox, but it refuses to budge. I've tried the flex-start/flex-end stuff, I've tried margin-right/left auto, but it doesn't seem to work.

The only thing that makes it work is if I put in a fix left margin, but when the screen size shrinks, it basically pushes the logo off the screen.

What's wrong with my code?

```css
/*Parent Element*/

#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}


/*Children*/

#logo {
  flex: 2;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  max-width: 6em;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#mobile-nav {
  flex: 1;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
  <div id="logo"><img src="./img/logo.png" alt=""> </div>
  <div id="mobile-nav">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <ul id="main-nav">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li><a href="''" class="btn">CTA</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: removing flex, justify-self and margin-right/left property from logo and mobile-nav should work in ideal cases unless another css is being implied on any of them.

Comment: hey @3Demon removing those items you suggested worked! I can't believe I've spent all day trying to figure this out when the solution was so simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
#nav-bar{
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo{}

#mobile-nav{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex `auto` margins work by consuming free space in the direction of the margin. For example, `margin-right: auto` consumes all free space to the right of the element. This has the effect of pinning the element and siblings on its left all the way to the left, while pinning siblings to its right all the way to the right.

The problem in your code is that you have `flex-grow` (via the `flex` shorthand property). Well, `flex-grow`, like `auto` margins, works by consuming free space. Since `flex-grow` distributes all free space on the line, there is nothing `auto` margins can do (there is no free space available for them to use).

The `justify-content` property also works through distribution of free space,  and will be useless when `flex-grow` is in play.

Solution: remove `flex-grow`.

Here's a more detailed explanation with illustrations:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I managed to get it to work in the end by using space between and getting rid of all the other CSS I had put in. Works perfectly now, although I've stumbled across a completely unrelated problem with the width of my page being too wide when I view it on my macbook compared to the PC I used to work from. Might have to pop by and ask you guys again if I can't figure it out haha.